# Updated: What data do I predict to obtain future forecast by shifting the closing price?

Tags: python, model, statistics, forecasting, quantitative-finance

I have written a Python code that makes predictions using statistics, machine learning, and deep learning models. However, I'll appreciate you pointing out what went wrong in the following idea(s) of mine when predicting the future price of a stock.

1. Download historical data.
2. Add technical indicators as features.
3. Create the target column by shifting the 'Adjusted Close' prices back by the number of days to predict, say 'days_to_predict', thereby obtaining NaNs in the empty cells.
4. Delete the 'Volume', 'Adj Close', 'Close', 'Low', 'Open', and 'High' columns.
5. Copy the last 'days_to_predict' rows in the feature array corresponding to NaNs into another variable called 'X_forecast'.
6. Delete those rows from features as well as the NaNs in target column.
7. Split the features and target arrays into training and test sets.
8. Carry out features/training set scaling.
9. Train the model using the train sets.
10. Test the model's performance using the test sets.
11. Use the model to predict X_forcast.

Although, I have put much effort into this, I am not getting an accurate result. My question is this: did I grab the wrong X_forecast? Kindly tell me what went wrong in my algorithm, or, better still, is there another way to grab X_forecast that is unknown to me?

Below is a sample code of just one day ahead:

```
import pandas_datareader as web
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta

start_date = '01/01/2004'
end_date = date.today()
ticker = 'TSLA'
data_source = 'yahoo' 
days_into_the_future = 1
test_size = 0.25

df = web.DataReader(ticker, data_source, start_date, end_date)
data = {}
data['df'] = df.copy()
data['df']['target'] = data['df']['Adj Close'].shift(-days_into_the_future)
data['df'] = data['df'].drop(['Volume','Adj Close','Close'],1)
data['X_forecast'] = data['df'].iloc[-days_into_the_future:,:-1]
data['df'] = data['df'].dropna()
data['feature'] = data['df'].drop(['target'],1)
data['target'] = data['df'].iloc[:,-1]

X = np.array(data['feature'])
y = np.array(data['target'])
timefeatures = data['feature'].index  

# split the dataset into training & testing sets by date
train_samples = int((1 - test_size) * len(X))
data["X_train"] = X[:train_samples]
data["y_train"] = y[:train_samples]
data["X_test"]  = X[train_samples:]
data["y_test"]  = y[train_samples:]
data["dates_train"] = timefeatures[:train_samples] # Extract the dates of train and test set dates
data["dates_test"] = timefeatures[train_samples:]

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
model = LinearRegression()
history = model.fit(data['X_train'],data['y_train']) 

predictionlineReg = history.predict(data['X_test'])  # Linear regression
predictionlineRegfuture = history.predict(data['X_forecast'])[0] # For tomorrow's prediction
```

Comment: Best would be to provide code and data. I suspect the problem is when selecting training and test sets in 7. you should be very careful doing that in time series. Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: @Rafael Valero, I have provided a sample code illustrating my idea.

Answer (score 0):

I see some problems:

1º) If you only use 1 input (adj close), the deep learning will be less precise
2º)If you use technicals as input of deeplearning, you will compromise deep learning coz the raw data is the prices(OHLC) and the technicals use OHLC . You should just use the raw data.
3º)from what I see this is not DL